# Use enum inside struct inside class?

Tags: c++, class, enums, struct

I have wrapped a struct around an enum to get a scoped enum.  E.g.:

```
namespace Xyz
{
    struct SortDirection
    {
        enum Enum {ASC, DESC};
    };

    class MyClass
    ...
```

This works fine.  Now I'm trying to define the same type of enum/struct combo but this time *inside* the class:

```
class MainDialog
{
public:
    ...
private:
    struct SomeType
        enum Columns {
        ROW_NUMBER_COLUMN,
        NAME_COLUMN,
        AGE_COLUMN,
        COLUMN_MAX_COUNT_
        };
    };

}
```

However this gives me an intellisense error:

> Error: invalid combination of type specifiers

When I try to compile I get:

```
1>c:\something\maindialog.h(80): error C2236: unexpected
'enum' 'MainDialog::Columns'. Did you forget a ';'?
```

The enum works fine *not* inside the struct, but as soon as I wrap it in a struct I get this error.

Comment: This is the turducken of data structures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
struct SomeType { // Note the open brace
```

Comment: I've been there... I suspect it's happened to all of us.

Answer (score 2):

You've missed an opening brace. The compiler sees `struct SomeType enum Columns` and doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

//This is right code.

```
private:     
    struct SomeType 
    {        
        enum Columns 
        {         
            ROW_NUMBER_COLUMN,
            NAME_COLUMN,
            AGE_COLUMN,
            COLUMN_MAX_COUNT_
        };
     };
```